# Display data inside input value using Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm fairly new to Jade and am wanting to display some outputted data as the `value` value of a text `input`. Like this:

```
input(type="text", name="date", value="THISRIGHTHURR")
```

But only the value needs to be `viewpost.date`. I've tried multiple ways and none seem to work:

```
input(type="text", name="date", value=viewpost.date) // doesn't work
input(type="text", name="date", value=.=viewpost.date) // doesn't work
input(type="text", name="date", value=".=viewpost.date") // doesn't work
```

I of course can get it to work outside of an `input` by doing something like

```
each post, i in viewpost
  h1.=post.date
```

Am I supposed to loop through in the `input` somehow too? This is the JS (using Node and Express) that's outputting my `viewpost` variable.

```
// render show post view
exports.viewpost = function(db) {
    return function(req, res) {
        var id = req.params.id;

        collection.find({ "_id": new BSON.ObjectID(id) }, function (err, data) {
            res.render("viewpost", {
                "viewpost" : data
            });
        });
    };
};
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try enclosing the variable in `#{}` to output it:

`input(type="text", name="date", value="#{viewpost.date}")`

Comment: Don't forget it's in a string!

Comment: This is outdated for Pug, view asym's answer below.

Answer (score 22):

Pug 0.1.0 (Jade 2.x) removed support for interpolation in attributes, so this works now:

```
input(type="text", name="date", value=viewpost.date)
```

See https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2305

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old news, but I found that neither of these worked, and ended up doing it like this, for anyone stumped like I was:

```
input(type="text", placeholder=data.string)
```

and then in a script:

```
$(document).on('focus', 'input', function(){
    var text = $(this).attr('placeholder');
    $(this).val(text);
})
```

thx