# Pug HTML Rendering With MongoDB ObjectID

Tags: node.js, pug

I have a HTML rendering problem on pug, I am sending the mongodb objectId to the .pug files and its not rendering properly.

My Pug Code :

```
 input(type='text', value=transaction._id, name='transaction_id')
```

HTML Rendered Code :

```
<input type="text" value="&quot;576c0bb18716a46c0c41508e&quot;" name="transaction_id"/>
```

Its automatically adding `&quot;` I tried to change the objectId as string, but it didn't works.

Comment: By default, `_id` in mongodb is of type `bson`. Probably, while displaying bson object, you are getting extra quotes. Either replace the text with `&quot;` to nospace or try to use `toString()`

Comment: I tried toString(), Not Works

Comment: what about `toHexString` ?

Comment: Try `value="#{transaction._id}"`

Comment: @MukeshSharma Sharma 2 hours ago

Comment: @Molda, I'm using pug, So this method not working. Ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300877/display-data-inside-input-value-using-jade

Answer (score -1):

This one should work :

```
 input(type='text', value='#{transaction._id}', name='transaction_id')
```

Comment: No, Not Working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300877/display-data-inside-input-value-using-jade

Comment: Yep you're right I assumed it's just like jade but it's not