# place nested object's properties within tag attribute in pug

Tags: javascript, html, pug

Given this object:

```
var script = {
  "steps": 
    [
      [ 
        {"usr":"u0", "act":"say", "msg":"this this"},
        {"usr":"u1", "act":"say", "msg":"that that"}
      ]
    ]
}
```

And this pug template:

```
html
    each stp, i in script.steps
        .step stp #{i}  
            br
            each obj in script.steps[i]     
                input(type='text', value='#{obj.msg}') 
                br
            br
```

I should get the .msg property of both nested objects in the value attribute of two text inputs as such:

```
<input type="text" value="this this">
<br/>
<input type="text" value="that that">
<br/>
```

But Instead I am getting:

```
<input type="text" value="#{obj.msg}">
<br/>
<input type="text" value="#{obj.msg}">
<br/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The documentation I am using is old for the version of pug I am using.

The correct syntax is:

```
input(type='text', value=obj.msg)
```

instead of:

```
input(type='text', value='#{obj.msg}')
```

As seen in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37096429/5721273